# Gwt SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay width

Tags: gwt

Is there any way to force the width of the DefaultSuggestionDisplay (i.e., the dropdown menu); I'd like to set for example : 250px. I'm trying with no success to tweak the CSS.

Comment: can you post some code of what you tried ? Did you try `@external gwt-suggestBoxPopup; .gwt-SuggestBoxPopup { width:250px;}`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your CSS file:

```
.suggestPopupMiddleCenter {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: That is not enough as there're several tables within the popup - I'm using table-layout:fixed as well and other ...